# To find eigenvalue,eigenvector by using python QR algorithm code

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I searched google to find python code , but only showing  QR decomposition algorithm

I want to know whole python code that exploits the shift method and iterative QR,RQ to find eigenvalue,eigenvector.

I have another question.   I read previous question of python implement QR that shows nonsymmetirc matrix not ensures accuracy eigenvector. is this true?

Comment: Try to keep your question specific. Provide more detail and any work you have done so far. If you are referencing another question you should link to it so we know more specifically what you are speaking to.

Comment: This is not very surprising, as the QR algorithm with shifts is usually implemented as an implicitly shifted method, the bulk of the QR transformation is done with the initial transformation to Hessenberg form and what remains are short-vector reflections that are enchained to a bulge-chasing algorithm, there is no state of an explicit QR decomposition identifiable after that.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the QR implementation in [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html)? That function seems to call the appropriate `*GEQRF` function in LAPACK: see [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L912-L917).